# JS Print Setup equivalent for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

Somebody knows a Google Chrome plugin or any solution to print without headers and custom margins?

https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/

JS Print Setup are a perfect solution for FF

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/457861/how-to-change-the-google-chrome-default-print-margins

visit above link it might help